# AWS Service for converting closed caption files

Tags: amazon-web-services, closed-captions, aws-media-convert

I have some closed caption files in .scc format.  I would like to convert them to .vtt format.  I have tried several online services and libraries and have had mixed success.  I was trying to identify an AWS service that would do the conversion (MediaConvert, Elastic Transcoder) but can't seem to figure out how to convert just a closed caption file when you don't have any actual media.

Do you know of an AWS service that can do the conversion?  Can you point me at a resource for getting started.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, no caption only support in MediaConvert today. But there is workaround to achieve your goal. You can use the MediaConvert and create a small SD output rendition (would need to make sure the source file had a matching duration [or longer]) and use the SCC has a sidecar file, and output the webvtt file, with a throw away video file.

Answer (score 0):

[ttconv](https://github.com/sandflow/ttconv) can convert SCC files to text-based formats, like TTML, IMSC, SRT, VTT...

```
pip install ttconv
tt.py convert -i <input .scc file> -o <output .ttml file>
```

As a pure python library, it can be [deployed on AWS as a lambda](https://ttconv.sandflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If good .scc support is important to you and command line tool is ok, [then you can use this](https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles):

```
php subtitles.phar input.scc output.vtt
```